# Open a url from flutter with long list or URL parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, urlencode, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I need to open a web page from flutter, and need to somehow pass a long list of data. I am currently creating a URL programmatically and passing the data through url parameters (ex www.mysite.com?param1=something&param2=... and opening the url with the url_launcher plugin. This is working just fine, until I create a url that is too long (which happens once in a while) giving me a http 431 error. I own the web page that I need to open, and can modify the way I am receiving data (get, post, etc).

A post request seems to be a better method than what I’m currently doing, but I’m lost as to how to send this data to the site within the body of a post request, and then open the site with this preloaded data.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you would do is make a post request and when that succeeds you would pass an id to the url you want to open that identifies the record you created in the post request - the next page would then query the rest api for the details associated with that id

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like an excellent Idea, I appreciate the feedback